# How do I create a list of pointers that point to objects within another list?

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm creating a simple graph where all nodes (or Vertices) are collected into a list.  Each node, in turn has a list of pointers that may point to multiple other nodes within the first list and call these edges.  For example, say I have a simple graph where `A -> B` and `A -> C` then Node `A` would have a list of pointers to `B` and `C` as it's edges.

As I create the graph, I first create the node, and populate it with anything pertinent to that node (weight or any other attributes).  I then add the node to the "Master" list of all nodes.  After that, I then pass the address of that node (now the last object in the list) into a function to add to any parent nodes:

`AddChildNode(&MasterListOfNodes.back(), NameOfParent)`

The following is the code for adding the child node to the parent

```
void GraphReader::AddChildNode(Vertex * const aChildVertex, const string aParent)
{
    for(list<Vertex>::iterator it = MasterListOfNodes.begin(); it != MasterListOfNodes.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it -> getName().compare(aParent) == 0)
        {
            it -> addEdge(aChildVertex);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Where addEdge simply adds the new Child to the Parents "Edges" list:

```
const void Vertex::addEdge(Vertex * aEdge) {mEdges.push_back(aEdge);}
```

The problem that I'm having, is that the list of edges are pointing to a copy of the list object, and not the actual object within the list itself:

[image: VS and Printout of Root Nodes and Edges]

Note: the addresses of the root nodes (command prompt output) were found with the following:

```
for (list<Vertex>::iterator it = MasterListOfNodes.begin(); it != MasterListOfNodes.end(); it++)
{
    cout << "Name: " << it->getName() << " | Address: {" << &(*it) << "}" << endl;
}
```

How do create my list of edges that point to the the master node?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Requirements (as this is a class assignment) state no outside libraries

Comment: Could you add the operations before `AddChildNode(&MasterListOfNodes.back(), NameOfParent)`? It's very unlikely that you do something wrong there, but just in case… Also, is there a reason why you add the nodes to `MasterListOfNodes` but print them from `mInternalGraph`?

Comment: @Zeta that was a copy pasta error. Sorry.

Comment: "The list of edges are pointing to a copy of the list object"? An edge has type `Vertex *`, how can it point to a `list<Vertex>` (unless you've been doing some bad casting)? I can't reproduce this error. Could you post a minimal complete example?

Answer (score 0):

When you use: `list<Vertex>` then list data-structure will manage how Vertex's are stored in memory

What you need to use is: `list<Vertex *>`

Example:

```
int main ()
{
    Vertex * a = new Vertex (..);

    list<Vertex*> v ();

    v.add(a);

    if (a == v[0])
    {
        // both points at the same Vertex in memory
    }

    return 0;
}
```